# Database Table For Holiday In MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm going to design a database table for holidays. But until now, I have no idea to do it.

Basically my ideal database table contains:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|Date   |Holiday Name |Location ID|
```

**There will be various type of holiday in different states in my country, so location ID plays a important role.

I have all those attributes, but I can't really use the date as my primary key. I assumed there will be two or more holiday or festival fall on the same date. I don't use the year of the holiday as primary key as well, because I want to keep all the records every year.

I am not really sure which or what primary key should I use to determine the holidays.

Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have a composite primary key `(date, holiday)`.

I would suggest making this a unique key in the table.  Then you can have an auto-incrementing column as the primary key.

It is not at all unusual to have overlapping holidays.  Easter and Passover often overlap.  Ramadan, in turn, cycles through the solar year and can overlap with any other (non-Muslim) holiday.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a composite primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE INFO (
  HolidayDate DATE,
  HolidayName VARCHAR(255),
  LocationID INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (HolidayDate , HolidayName, LocationID);
)
```

This means that there could be no 2 holidays in the same location and the same date.